# .load pcre.so from command line

Tags: sqlite

I'm running some command line sqlite3 queries (sqlite 2.8.17 Linux Mint 18.02) using regexp. This produces the error:

`Error: no such function: REGEXP`

I've already installed sqlite3-pcre. If I run sqlite3 interactively, I can successfully run my query after executing `.load /usr/lib/sqlite3/pcre.so`

Attempting to load the library on the command line produces an error:

`sqlite3 my.db ".load /usr/lib/sqlite3/pcre.so;select * from foo where description REGEXP 'Some Expression'"
Error: /usr/lib/sqlite3/pcre.so;select.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How do I include the .load with my command-line query? Can I put the library in an rc file somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Seemed obvious once I conceptualized the question about putting options in an rc file:

`$ cat ~/.sqliterc 
.load /usr/lib/sqlite3/pcre.so`